# Comparison test of sequence with complex exponent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

I have some $\mathbf{n}\in \mathbb{Z}^N$ ($N\geq 2$) with $\mathbf{n}\not=\mathbf{0}$. I have  the series $$S=\sum_{\mathbf{n}\not=\mathbf{0}} \frac{1}{||\mathbf{n}||^{2s}},$$ where $s\in\mathbb{C}$ is fixed. The book states that 'by a simple comparison test', $S<\infty$ when $\Re(s) > \frac{N}{2}.$

I'm not sure how to interpret this statement. I assume that the series can be written $$\sum_{\mathbf{n}\not=\mathbf{0}} \left\{ \frac{e^{-i2\Im(s)\ln(||\mathbf{n}||)}}{||\mathbf{n}||^{2\Re(s)}} \right\}.$$

Now I'm not sure how one does a comparison test on this series. Presumably the comparison being made is $$\left|\frac{e^{-i2\Im(s)\ln(||\mathbf{n}||)}}{||\mathbf{n}||^{2\Re(s)}}\right| =\left|\frac{1}{||\mathbf{n}||^{2\Re(s)}}\right| \leq \frac{1}{||\mathbf{n}||^{N}}\leq \frac{1}{||\mathbf{n}||^2}.$$ Is it correct that since $||\mathbf{n}||>1$, the absolute value of the terms in the curly braces above will converge regardless of the order in which we sum them? Then does this imply that $S$ is absolutely convergent for $\Re(s)>\frac{N}{2}.$ Presumably also this condition on $s$ is certainly sufficient, but the necessary condition is only that $\Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}$?

Is this the general approach that one takes for a series with a complex power?

Comment: We have $$\sum_{\mathbf{n}\neq0}\left|\frac{1}{\|\mathbf{n}\|^{2s}}\right|=\sum_{\mathbf{n}\neq0}\frac{1}{\|\mathbf{n}\|^{2\operatorname{Re}(s)}} \leq C \int\limits_{\substack{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^N\\\|\mathbf{x}\|\geq1}} \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|^{2\operatorname{Re}(s)}} $$ for some finite constant $C$, and this bound converges if $2\operatorname{Re}(s)>N$. Moreover, this idea can be pushed further to show that $S$ converges absolutely if and only if $\operatorname{Re}(s)>N/2$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Do you have any sources where I may see examples like this, I'm not familiar with what $\sum_{n\not=0}$ would mean in terms of order, and indeed am a bit unfamiliar with what $\int_{x\in\mathbb{R}^N, |x|\geq 1}$ would mean. Is this just $\int_1^\infty$ of $\frac{1}{y^{2 Re(s)}}$?

Comment: As you pointed out, the order usually matters in the ordinary sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$. But it turns out that, if the series converges absolutely, then the order does not matter at all. In fact, even a more general observation holds: Let $f:A\to\mathbb{C}$ be a function. $$\text{If }\sup_{\substack{F\subseteq A\\F\text{ finite}}}\sum_{a\in F}|f(a)|<\infty,\qquad\text{then }\lim_{\substack{F\uparrow A\\F\text{ finite}}}\sum_{a\in F}f(a)\text{ converges}.$$ This idea can be used to defined summations such as $\sum_{\mathbf{n}\in\mathbb{Z}^N\setminus\{\mathbf{0}\}}$ given absolute convergence.

Comment: Next, $\int_{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^N,\|\mathbf{x}\|\geq 1}$ is an integral over the $N$-dimensional set $\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^N:\|\mathbf{x}\|\geq1\}$. For instance, when $N=2$, $$\int\limits_{\substack{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^N\\\|\mathbf{\mathbf{x}}\|\geq 1}}f(\mathbf{x})\,\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}=\iint\limits_{x^2+y^2\geq1}f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$ and similarly for arbitrary $N$.